# Sprite Zoom in and zoom out animation in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I am developing a game in libgdx where I need to zoom in and zoom out a popup for clearing every stage in the game. Could you please guide me how to do zoom effects in libgdx. 
Just a note I am doing this for android device.

Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

You can zoom using the property of same name of OrtographicCamera.

```
camera.zoom = 1; //Normal zoom (default)

camera.zoom = 2; //Zoomed in

camera.zoom = 0.5F; //Zoomed out
```

If you mean "zooming" a particular image, then just make it bigger and smaller.

Answer (score 0):

To make your sprite larger or smaller use sprite.setScale, where 1 is the default size, 2 is 2 time bigger, 0.5 half.. you understand.

But if you want to make like a screen transition better use camera zoom, as described in the post above.